# How to reorder the C++ standard precedence of arithmetic operators, so that subtraction will have higher priority

Tags: c++, string, oop, operators, calculator

I want to make a calculator, which will ask u the precedence of arithmetic  operators.For example priority №1 for addition,№2 for division, №3 for subtraction, №4 for multiplication.
The question is : Do i need to use to overload operators or just simply use parenthesis?

Comment: C++'s own operator precedence has nothing to do with the operator precedence in the grammar of your calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can achieve the equivalent of manipulating the precedence of operators using operator overloading - it would involve introducing your own classes and performing the operations on them.

When implementing an operation that you want to lower the priority of, you implement it by storing the 2 values and either storing the operation or returning a class specific to that operation. 
When converting back to a result you apply the stored operations in your chosen order.

Example with + higher precedence than * :-

```
struct Multiple;

struct Number
{
    Number(double val)
        : m_Val(val)
    {}

    friend double operator+(const Multiple& left, const Number& right);
    friend Multiple operator*(const Number& left, const Number& right);

    private:
    double m_Val;

};

struct Multiple
{
    Multiple(double left, double right)
      : m_left(left),
        m_right(right)
    {}

    friend double operator+(const Multiple& left, const Number& right);

    private:
    double m_left;
    double m_right;
};

Multiple operator*(const Number& left, const Number& right)
{
    return Multiple(left.m_Val, right.m_Val);
}

double operator+(const Multiple& a, const Number& b)
{
    return a.m_left * (a.m_right + b.m_Val);
}


void main()
{
    Number a(3);
    Number b(1);
    Number c(2);

    double d = a * b + c;
    // d = 9 (not 5)
}
```

But in your question you say something about just using brackets - its not clear to me exactly what you're doing but if you can do it just by adding brackets then that sounds more simple.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manipulate the precedence of operators when doing operator overloading.

Normally, operator precedence is hard-wired into the *grammar* associated with your expressions. That is the case in C++ for example.

The challenge of your project is that you want to make the grammar flexible at run-time. You're stumbling upon *dynamic programming languages* at this point. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language for further reading.

What you want to do is, of course, possible, but you'll have to be careful in how you build your parser and lexical analysers.